# NodeJS deep nested json comparison case insensitive key/value pair

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ecmascript-6, lodash

I want to compare two nested json in NodeJS, json key position can change and also key/value comparison should bee case insensitive

I'm using deep-equal NodeJS module, but it's only working for case sensitive comparison

```
let json1 = {
  "type": "NEW",
  "users": [{
    "id": "dskd3782shdsui",
    "email": "helloworld@xxxxxx.com"

  }],
  "ordered": [{
    "productId": "SHFDHS37463",
    "SKU": "ffgh"
  }]
}

let json2 = {
  "type": "NEW",
  "users": [{
    "id": "dskd3782shdsui",
    "email": "helloworld@xxxxxx.com"

  }],
  "ordered": [{
    "productId": "SHFDHS37463",
    "SKU": "ffgh"
  }]
}

var deepEqual = require('deep-equal')

console.log('==', deepEqual(
  json1,
  json2
))
```

Above code is working but if I change json2 email to helloworld@xxxxxx.COM or email key to EMAIL it's returning false I want case insensitive comparison.

Comment: How about that:
```JSON.stringify(json1).toLowerCase() == JSON.stringify(json2).toLowerCase()```

Comment: This will not work if you change json key position.

Comment: if you get both objects from JSON strings, you can convert them to lowercase before parsing and `deepEqual`. Otherwise, you can `JSON.stringify`, `toLowerCase`, and `JSON.parse` both before `deepEqual`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for this it will work for both key/value case insensitive and also if we change key position

```
var deepEqual = require('deep-equal')

function toLower(a) {
 return JSON.stringify(a).toLowerCase();
}


console.log('==', deepEqual(
    JSON.parse(toLower(json1)),
    JSON.parse(toLower(json2))
) )
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle case insensitive comparisons between string values (this won't work for keys), you can use lodash's [`_.isEqualWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqualWith) with a customizer function:

```js
const obj1 = {"type":"NEW","users":[{"id":"dskd3782shdsui","email":"helloworld@xxxxxx.COM"}],"ordered":[{"productId":"SHFDHS37463","SKU":"ffgh"}]}
const obj2 = {"type":"new","users":[{"id":"dskd3782shdsui","email":"helloworld@xxxxxx.com"}],"ordered":[{"productId":"SHFDHS37463","SKU":"ffgh"}]}

const result = _.isEqualWith(
  obj1, 
  obj2, 
  (objValue, othValue) =>  _.isString(objValue) && _.isString(othValue) ?
    objValue.toLowerCase() === othValue.toLowerCase()
    :
    undefined
)

console.log('==', result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

To handle keys with different cases, you should normalize the keys to lower case, and then make the comparison. I've use [`_.transform()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#transform) to create a recursive function that iterates a nested object, and converts all keys to lower case.

```js
const normaliseKeys = obj => _.transform((r, k, v) => {
  const key = _.isString(k) ? k.toLowerCase() : k;
  
  r[key] = _.isObject(v) ? normaliseKeys(v) : v;
})

const obj1 = normaliseKeys({"TYPE":"NEW","users":[{"id":"dskd3782shdsui","EMAIL":"helloworld@xxxxxx.COM"}],"ordered":[{"productId":"SHFDHS37463","SKU":"ffgh"}]})
const obj2 = normaliseKeys({"type":"new","users":[{"id":"dskd3782shdsui","email":"helloworld@xxxxxx.com"}],"ordered":[{"productId":"SHFDHS37463","SKU":"ffgh"}]})

const result = _.isEqualWith(
  obj1,
  obj2, 
  (objValue, othValue) =>  _.isString(objValue) && _.isString(othValue) ?
    objValue.toLowerCase() === othValue.toLowerCase()
    :
    undefined
)

console.log('==', result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u don't mind using https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqualWith

```
var result = _.isEqualWith(json1, json2, (value1, value2, key) => { 
    console.log(value1, value2);
    //check for string and compare
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
function jsonEqual(a,b) {
    return JSON.stringify(a).toLowerCase() === JSON.stringify(b).toLowerCase();
}
console.log(jsonEqual(json1, json2))
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zb7erkc3/).

Comment: This will not work if you change json key position.

Comment: My apologies, I forget "json key positionjson" in your question